# Show that the cyclic group $C_n$ has the simples factors $C_{p_i}$ with the multiplicity $m_i$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $n=p_1^{m_1}p_2^{m_2}\cdots p_s^{m_s}$ the decomposition in factors of
>   the natural number $n$. Show that the cyclic group $C_n$ has the
>   simples factors $C_{p_i}$ with the multiplicity $m_i$.

This subject is related to the Jordan-Hölder theorem.

I really don't understand how to do this problem. Is anyone can give me a hint to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cyclic group of order $n$ has exactly one subgroup of order $k$ where $k|n$, so there is a unique subgroup $P_i$ of order $p_i^{m_i}$ **(Sylow)**.

If $i \ne j$ then $P_i \cap P_j$ is the identity, since the order of any other element would have to be simultaneously a power of two distinct primes.

Perhaps you can use these facts to develop your required structure result.

added in response to OP's question:

the hint above allows you to construct a chain of subgroups $0=G_0 \triangleleft G_1 \triangleleft G_2 \dots \triangleleft G_s=G$ in which the order of $G_j$ is $\prod_{i=1}^j p_i^{m_i}$

although different orderings of the set of primes produce different chains you will notice that the *set* of factor groups $\{G_j/G_{j-1}\}_{j=1,\dots,s}$ is always the same, consisting of the Sylow subgroups $C_{p_i}^{m_i}$

so you now need to refine this chain so that each factor group is isomorphic to one of the simple cyclic groups $C_{p_i}$. you can see that if this can be done, then from considering the orders we see $C_{p_i}$ must occur with multiplicity $m_i$.

so you need only one further result, concerning the structure of a cyclic group whose order is a power of a prime. i will leave that with you for now. it is not so difficult

Comment: What is the meaning of  '' the simples factors $C_{p_i}$ with the multiplicity $m_i$''?